# Why did the salesman not accept the ticket without even looking at it?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-family-man

In *The Family Man* (2000), Cash had won a $238 lottery ticket, so he went to a salesman to get the money on the winning lottery ticket, but the salesman didn’t accept the lottery ticket without looking at it. I don’t understand why the salesman was ignoring his prize money.

[image]

Later, Jack gave his $200 to Cash in return for the lottery ticket.
In the image above, Cash is shown with a gun in his hand, which he pulled out after the salesman did not accept the ticket.

---

Note: Cash is name of the role.

Comment: https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/familyman.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the book ***Racial Stigma on the Hollywood Screen from World War II to the Present: The Orientalist Buddy Film*** by **Brian Locke**:

> Hollywood films participated in driving the same wedge between black and Asian. In *The Family Man* (Brett Ratner, 2000), a reiter-ation of the Christmas classic *It's a Wonderful Life* (Frank Capra, 1946), **a patronizing Asian male deli clerk (Ken Leung) refuses to honor a black patron's lottery ticket because of his racial prejudice.** "You get out now!" the young Asian yells in an "Oriental" accent. "You take the ticket somewhere else!"